# Cómo almacenar claves de usuario en Seahorse

Tags: ubuntu, seguridad, shell

Estoy trabajando sobre un Ubuntu 15.10. Utilizando un script quiero recoger dos variables (*user* y *pass*) y, mediante un comando de consola, guardarlo en el gestor de Claves Seahorse (en realidad me valdría con cualquiera).

¿Alguna idea?